# Regarding CCAvenue integration in iOS

Tags: ios, mobile, payment-gateway, ccavenue

Hi guys please guide me through the following questions.

1. What is the best payment gateway option to go in my iOS mobile app.
2. If i choose CCAvenue what are the basic steps to follow.

Comment: does any 1 know answer ?

Comment: refer answer of this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33207668/ccavenue-ios-kit-integration-kit