# CCAvenue iOS kit integration kit

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, payment-gateway, ccavenue

I am trying to integrate CCAvenue payment integration in iOS. They have given me two library files named: `libcrypto.a` and `libssl.a`

They have also given me some header files.

To implement this, they have mentioned that I should to setup header search paths and library search paths in the build settings.

I have set them both but I getting the following error:

> ERROR : `openssl/rsa.a` file not found.

Can anybody help me step by step with copying these files to my project and setting up the proper path and flags if needed?

I am working with Xcode 7.0.1 and iOS 7.0+

Comment: I am also facing same problem, any one having idea how to implement in iOS, Please give step by step process of implementation .

Comment: @rayryeng  has anyone got a solution to this, i am facing the same issue?

Comment: @Pranav Gupte did you solve it , i am facing the same issue?

Comment: @OmkarGuhilot I only edited this post for grammar. I'm not an iOS expert. Please don't ping me any further. Thanks.

Comment: @  Omkar Guhilot : Check my answer below. I have resolved for simulator and device both.

Comment: hi guys, i am also facing same issue pls help any one?

Comment: opens ssl frame work get missed from your project. kindly  add the open ssl framework to your project.

Comment: @pranav gupte Hi peanav i am facing the same issue I tried karans answer but still i am unable to sucess

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I have achieved today only for IOS 9. To run just you need to download api from [CCAvenue](https://login.ccavenue.com/resources/)

We will **Re Add** by drag and drop `openssl/` and `lib/` folders

After downloading follow these steps:

1. Delete old reference of from `framework`/`build phases`
2. You will find 2 folders `openssl/` and `lib/` under `Openssl/openssl-1.0.1i-iOS` folder.
3. Just drag drop each folder under `Frameworks` folder and **DON'T FORGET TO CHECK COPY FILES IF NEEDED.**
4. Also under `Build Settings` of project go for `Search Paths`->`Library Search Paths` remove what is provided `Users/test/desktop/....` and add $(PROJECT_DIR) again add $(inherited)
5. Do 4th step for `Search Paths`->`User Header Search Paths`.remove and add same as 4th step.
6. Compile you will find error gone.

**I tested in Simulator working fine.**

**On Device**

on device build was failed. To run on Device also.

1. I set `Enable Bitcode` to `NO`under `Build Options` for project
2. Rebuild again and error gone.

Comment: Please share what credential  need to integrate

Comment: hi, we have to add the folder openssl/ and lib or the files inside openssl/ and lib/

Comment: Add the folders along with the files and not only the file alone

Comment: i follow your step but then also i get "error encounter".can you tell me when and why this error is popup?where i am missing

Comment: @NayabKhan could u help me to implement this in swift

Answer (score 3):

**I have resolve error by using following steps.**

```
Step 1:- Download CCAvenue iOS SDK https://www.ccavenue.com/inapp_payments.jsp 
Step 2:- Delete old reference of from framework/build phases and Clean your app.
Step 3:- You get 2 folders openssl/ and lib/ under Openssl/openssl-1.0.1i-iOS folder.
Step 4:- Copy that folder "openssl-1.0.1i" in your project.
Step 5:- Drag and drop include and lib folder under Frameworks folder and DON'T FORGET TO CHECK COPY FILES IF NEEDED.
Step 6:- In User Header Search Paths write these line. /Users/YOUR_SYSTEM_USER_NAME/PROJECT_SAVED_LOCATION/APP_NMAE/openssl-1.0.1i/include || for example my location is "/Users/CharlePrabhat/Desktop/TestApp/Openssl/include"
Step 7:- Clean and compile you will find everything is fine.
```

**I have tested on my device its perfect running. Hope it will help you.**

Answer (score 1):

I have user pod 'OpenSSL-Universal' library which resolves my all Openssl dependancies

Add below line in podfile

**pod 'OpenSSL-Universal'**

hit command pod install from terminal