# ccavenue mobile app integration in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone

Can any one could explain,how to integrate the **CCAvenue** mobile integration.already i download the api from **CCAvenue** website even though i can't understand.

I tried sample code from **CCAvenue** API although some `error`.
like this **'openssl/rsa.h' file not found**

Comment: Check my answer below. I have resolved for simulator and device both.

Comment: please check answer I have already answered. http://stackoverflow.com/a/36840859/3172518

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Three simple steps:

- (1) Go to Build Setting ,
- (2) add your (openssl ios) lib path on libray search path ,
- (3) add your (openssl ios) include path on user Header Search path

[image]