# Ccavenue payment integration in ios objective c

Tags: ios, objective-c

Hello any one help me how to integrate Ccavenue Payment integration in objective c. i am trying it's sdk it having Openssl error please help me how i done it step by step.

Thank you.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [CCAvenue iOS kit integration kit](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33207668/ccavenue-ios-kit-integration-kit)

Comment: **Check this link** http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33407119/ccavenue-mobile-app-integration-in-ios/39804877#39804877