# while ccavenue payment gateway integration i am getting the following error

Tags: objective-c

[image: pls refer the image]
1) Unknown type name 'XSym'
2) Expected identifier or '('
3) '@end' must appear in an Objective-C context
 can anyone pls give me the suggestion how to solve this problem while integrating the ccavenue ...

Comment: show the parts of your code that have these errors

Comment: @vitormm i added the image please check it.

Comment: This is not a proper `.h` file... I see that it's inside an `openssl` framework. Where did you downloaded it from? What are you trying to use it for?

Comment: i just followed this steps http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33207668/ccavenue-ios-kit-integration-kit .i added the openssl and lib files what they provided inside the project .