# How to compile xcode project?

Tags: ios, xcode

I have an Xcode project for an iOS app as a legacy project. Full source code, it works 100%. I need to publish it to AppStore. But I have never used Xcode, macOS or done any ios app development related stuff and I have problems to compile it and not sure if I am doing it correctly.

I tried "Product->Run" and "Product->Build". I always get "Build Failed" and some errors. In the navbar, I choose "iPhone 7 (10.3.1)" and some other versions as well. Errors I get -

[image]

But as I mentioned, it is a finished app and I don't feel I should be making any changes to the code and not to a 3rd party code (SDWebImage).

I want to compile this project so I get the .ipa file. What is the step-by-step approach to getting a .ipa file from source code?

Comment: I find the filepaths mentioned in errors suspicious. Your xcode should not be pointing to dependencies in the system downloads folder. Does this path even exist on your machine? Its possible the creator pointed them to his own machines downloads folder and then saved the project, which is the wrong thing to do. Dependencies should be inside the project folder, otherwise it can't be shared

Comment: The project folder is in my Downloads currently. Dependencies are in that project folder in "Pods" folder so it seems correct (inside the project folder).

Comment: List everything you have done. Did you clone it from source control? Did you download it from a file sharing service? did you run `pod install` to make sure cocoapods has the dependencies correctly? you mentioned its a legacy app, are you using the same version of xcode that was used?

Comment: 1. Downloaded .zip archive. 2. Unzip by double click. 3. Open Xcode 10.3. 4. Open projects .xcodeproj file. 5. Tried "Product->Run". Pretty sure it isn't same version of xcode that was used before because the app was created at 2015-2017.

Comment: the `XSym` issue is an issue with the way the third party libraries were imported (similar question here without an answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43042892/while-ccavenue-payment-gateway-integration-i-am-getting-the-following-error). I would delete the pods folder and run `pod install` again to see if it pulls everything down. Also if its a zipped copy of the project and not coming directly from source control, you have no way of knowing if this is in fact the version of the app that was running perfectly before. This happens all the time.

Comment: Did the `pod install` and it solved my issue. Thanks!

Comment: Ok, since that fixed the issue i've added that as an answer instead of a comment. Please upvote/accept the answer to close the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You mentioned in the comments that you downloaded and unpacked a .zip of the project. Your issues are most likely caused by a conflict in the way the dependencies were setup.

Try delete the `pods` folder and run `pod install` in terminal, in the root project folder, to re-install all the project dependencies.