# CCAvenue "Error Encountered.ERROR

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have integrated CCAvenue into my app but problem is when code is hitting

> https://secure.ccavenue.com/transaction/initTrans

below is the code :

```
NSString *encryptedStr = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Merchant_Id=%@&Order_Id=%@&redirect_url=%@&cancel_url=%@&enc_val=%@&access_code=AVSB00EA86CN75BSNC&billing_name=%@&billing_address =%@&billing_city=%@&billing_state=%@&billing_zip=%@&billing_country=%@&billing_email=%@&billing_tel=%@",MerchantID,_order_id,redirectUrl,cancelUrl,encVal,self.billing_name,self.billing_address,self.billing_city,self.billing_state,self.billing_zip,self.billing_country,self.billing_email,self.billing_tel];
NSData *myRequestData = [NSData dataWithBytes: [encryptedStr UTF8String] length: [encryptedStr length]];
NSMutableURLRequest *requestN = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] initWithURL: [NSURL URLWithString: urlAsString]];
[requestN setValue:@"application/x-www-form-urlencoded" forHTTPHeaderField:@"content-type"];
[requestN setValue:urlAsString forHTTPHeaderField:@"Referer"];
[requestN setHTTPMethod: @"POST"];
[requestN setHTTPBody: myRequestData];
[self.webView loadRequest:requestN];
```

Every time its returning

> Error Encountered.ERROR!! Problem in decrypting application request

Comment: see this : http://stackoverflow.com/a/36840859/3901620

Comment: I already integrated ccavenue non-shameless method... there documentation is not clear.... for that ... I think u r also facing same issue

Comment: did you checked @Anjali Singh

Answer (score 0):

> this is the solution for non-shameless ... I think only difference is regarding the payment details(non-shameless and shameless) ... only .
>   this is working for me I hope it will resolve ur issue ... and check that are u hitting the ccavenue server through ur mobile with in 120 sec or not after u getting the rsa key.u need to hit the ccavenue server(with in 120 sec) for billing page otherwise it will expire.

**try this:**

from server:

> once u hit the ccavenue sever for **RSA** key with ur accesscode and orderID
>
> u will get : rsa key for ur transaction.
>
> u need to encrypt the key with **base64** and **AES-256** format.
>
> before u encrypt u need to **remove** some unnecessary data in a key
>
> 1.double quotes in a key
>
> 2. \n in the key
> 3. \ in a key

```
   // removing double quates
            NSString * newReplacedString2 = [rsaKey stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"\"" withString:@""];

            NSLog(@"%@",rsaKey);

            //removing \n in the key
            NSString * newReplacedString = [newReplacedString2 stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"\\n" withString:@""];

            NSLog(@"%@",rsaKey);
        //removing \ in the key
        NSString * newReplacedString1 = [newReplacedString stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"\\" withString:@""];
        NSLog(@"%@",newReplacedString1);

//and u need to divide the key for every 64 bits 

    NSString * abc = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", newReplacedString1];
    NSMutableString *sss=[NSMutableString new];
    int j=(int)([abc length]/63);
    for (int i=0; i<=j; i++) {
        int k= i*63;
        NSString * newString;
        if (i != j) {
            newString = [abc substringWithRange:NSMakeRange(k,63)];
            NSLog(@"%lu",(unsigned long)newString.length);
            newString=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",newString];
        }else{
            newString = [abc substringWithRange:NSMakeRange(k,[abc length]-k)];
            NSLog(@"%lu",(unsigned long)newString.length);
            if (newString.length !=0)
                newString=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",newString];
        }
        if (newString.length !=0)
            [sss appendString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@\n",newString]];
    }
    NSLog(@"%@",sss);

     //as per the documentation u can follow the process 
    rsaKey = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----\n%@-----END PUBLIC KEY-----\n",sss];
    NSLog(@"%@",rsaKey);

    //Encrypting Card Details
        NSString *myRequestString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"amount=%@&currency=%@",amount,currency];
        CCTool *ccTool = [[CCTool alloc] init];


    NSLog(@"emcrpted data %@",[ccTool encryptRSA:myRequestString key:rsaKey]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Solution for Non Seamless Integration in Swift .

In my case, I got same message .

> Error Encountered.ERROR!! Problem in decrypting application request

You need to **call/mail** to **ccavenue support team** for any concern .

They will provide you solution or new integration kit .

[CCAvenue Support Mail](http://service@ccavenue.com)