# ccavenue 'openssl/pem.h' file not found

Tags: ios, swift, openssl, ccavenue

I am integrating ccavenue is my swift project everything going fine but i am getting just one error like below

**Error**

`'openssl/pem.h' file not found`

i tried to search and i was find answer with this question and i also tried all i have share some link which i have tried

1. https://stackoverflow.com/a/36840859/10804348
2. https://stackoverflow.com/a/43685926/10804348

i have tried all the steps which are mention in below answer but not working for me please give me suggestion for this

Comment: Did you reference that include in your `Bridging Header` file?  Have you got a universal `OpenSSL` build ( one for arm and one for simulators )? I had `OpenSSL` static libraries and header files integrated into my Swift code but I found it easier to integrate `curl.h` and `curl.a`.  These used `openssl` under the hood.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have forgot to add

*
Step 6:- In User Header Search Paths write these line. /Users/YOUR_SYSTEM_USER_NAME/PROJECT_SAVED_LOCATION/APP_NMAE/openssl-1.0.1i/include || for example my location is "/Users/CharlePrabhat/Desktop/TestApp/Openssl/include"
*

I had the same issue. I have solved it by adding header search path for ccAvenue.